# Do I need to give id_cart as primary key in database mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

So i'm working on a website which can be launched using xampp localhost. The website is about online shopping. I'm having a problem with saving the cart datas to the table with only 1 primary key and saving those said datas to another table too.

Here's the type of data from the cart table that i've created on my database :

CART TABLE

- cart_id (primary key)
- customer_id
- product_id
- quantity

if i added 2 different products then it'll save the cart data to the database, which resulted in 2 different primary keys

and then i've made the order_transaction table with these data types :

ORDER_TRANSACTION TABLE

- order_id (primary key)
- customer_id
- cart_id
- date_time
- total_payment
- payment_method
- payment_status
- name
- phone
- address
- courier_name
- shipping_fee

the question is, how do i put the cart datas to the order_transaction table with only 1 primary key needed ? And which one needs to be set as foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

In Cart Table, You can create 3 columns primary key (Composite Key)
because cart_id will not be unique itself, and cart_id + customer_id will also not be unique so adding product_id to it should make it unique.

```
ALTER TABLE cart ADD PRIMARY KEY(cart_id, customer_id , product_id );
```

and i believe if the user selects the same product again, it should not insert the record, instead update the quantity. if so then this should work fine.

Use cart_id and customer_id in the join

Comment: did you mean in the order_transaction table? Can you give me some example so I can understand it clearly ? Scribble/picture is fine, thankyou !

Comment: I tried to create a sample fiddle, check if this  [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pPndjGYVppoKwHHRHYWMXd/1) working for you,  or this is what you looking for

Comment: thank you vary much for sparing the time to make the sample ! I've taken a look at your sample and I noticed that for 2 different customer_id ,they can have the same cart_id (customer_id 1 with cart_id 1 and customer_id 3 with cart_id 1), is that true?  I assume the data won't be redundant?

Comment: and also I've tried added 2 different products to the cart, but both of them has different cart_id.... How to make them have the same cart_id with mysqli query?

Comment: actually in cart table, 3 columns make up a primary key together. so cart id 1 + customer 1 and order 1 is unique, 111, then cart 1 customer 2 order 1, 121  is unique. 
so your primary key is not just cart_id , its also customer + product id

Comment: cart id should not be auto increment in this case, you can fetch  the new cart_id by customer id, search the cart table for the customer and get the last cart_id and add 1 to it for new cart_id

Comment: okay I understand your solution so far, I'll try to implement it and see if it works. But what will happen if I wanted to show detailed datas from a specific order id ? Will I need a different mysqli query to fetch the cart datas or use the OT datas and join function ?